# JS: Split function into kind of module parts

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I would like to structure this code in a better way by building some kind of modules. I'm using ES6, so I tried to use `import` / `export`.

**Example function**

```
function() {
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#canvas'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1
    });

    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });

    var rect2 = rect.clone();
    rect2.translate(300);

    var link = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id }
    });

    graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
}
```

So I would like to get something like this, which would be much better readable:

**script.js**

```
import * from './config.js';

function() {
    var graph = graph();
    var paper = paper();
    var rect = rect();
    var rect2 = rect.clone();
    rect2.translate(300);
    var link = link();

    graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
}
```

And all the content should be in another file:

**config.js**

```
export 
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph,
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#canvas'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});
// ...
```

But this attempt has not the correct syntax. How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this attempt has not the correct syntax.

You are looking for

```
export const graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
export const paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#canvas'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});
…
```

However, you'll need to wrap them in functions so that importing the module doesn't execute any side effects and you can reuse them (call them multiple times when the function you are creating is called). You'd look for

```
export function graph() {
    return new joint.dia.Graph;
}
export function paper(graph) {
    return new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#canvas'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1
    });
}
export function rect() {
    return new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' },
        text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });
}
export function link(rect1, rect2) {
    return new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id }
    });
}
```

so that you can use

```
import {graph, paper, rect, link} from "…"

export default function() {
    const g = graph(),
          p = paper(g),
          r1 = rect(),
          r2 = r.clone();
    r2.translate(300);

    g.addCells([r1, r2, link(r1, r2)]);
}
```

However, I don't think that your code really benefits from being spread across multiple modules. As long as you cannot reuse any of those functions, you should just inline them, they're quite specific.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give name to your exported methods and your imported module.

Try this code.

Script.js

```
import * as config from './config.js';

function() {
    var graph = config.graph();
    var paper = config.paper();
    var rect = config.rect();
    var rect2 = config.rect.clone();
    rect2 = rect2.translate(300);
    var link = config.link();

    config.graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
}
```

Config.js

```
export {graph as graph, paper as paper}
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#canvas'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph,
    gridSize: 1
});
// ...
```